# Complex sql update Query

Tags: sql

I have table like

```
Ticker Sedol  bbg    identifier
t1      w2    null     Ticker
t2      w3    null      sedol
```

If identfier is ticker then bbg is updated with ticker column value and same to sedol identifier.But If i insert new identidier in identifier column then it should work for that also.
Ex if i insert 'occ' in  identifier column  the bbg column should be updated with occ column value.
I will add occ column after inserting identifier value.

I want ouput like...

```
Ticker Sedol  bbg    identifier
t1      w2    t1     Ticker
t2      w3    w3      sedol
```

Note:Query should be dynamic

Comment: What? Do you have one or two tables?

Comment: This probably shouldn't be in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for dynamic, but won't this do?

```
UPDATE TableName
SET    bbg = CASE
                WHEN identifier = 'Ticker'
                THEN Ticker
                WHEN identifier = 'Sedol'
                THEN Sedol
                WHEN identifier = 'occ'
                THEN occ
             END
```

Dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TableName
            SET    bbg = CASE ' +
            STUFF
            (
                (
                    SELECT ' ' + 'WHEN identifier = ''' + c.name + ''' THEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
                    FROM   sys.columns c
                           JOIN sys.tables t 
                               ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                    WHERE t.name = 'YourTableName'
                          AND c.name <> 'bbg'
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 
                1, 
                0, 
                ''
            ) + ' END'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

And a nice **<kbd>FIDDLER Demo</kbd>** to prove my case....